# Appending url direct in mvc controller

Tags: json, html, asp.net-mvc-5

having a problem since i deployed my app.  A lot of pages aren't loading because if i have either configured it wrong i created it wrong.

I have this line in my controllers:

```
return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = (@Url.Content("~/Maintenance/_TitleDetails")) }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

(based it from what i use in my view which works.  but it loads the url as

```
 Http://Ip..../~/Maintenance_TitleDetails
```

and as such is failing because there should be the App name where the ~ is.

This works for the view put is probably razor specific.

Having the same issue for Html generated links also.  Can someone point me in the right direction please as best way of doing this?

EDIT

Have tried to capture the context in C# but failed with this also.

```
System.Web.HttpContext curContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = (curContext + ("/Maintenance/_TitleDetails")) }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

http://162.168.0.1/System.Web.HttpContext/Maintenance/_TitleDetails 404 (Not Found)

edit 2
works with

```
string baseUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');

            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = (baseUrl + ("/Maintenance/_TitleDetails")) }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

but wondering if there is a better way of doing it rather than having that in every controller action?

Comment: Have you tried removing Url.Content call? Since last razor versions it's not needed at all to reference web root and ~ inside the route is enough

Comment: Hi, yes I had it as 

return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = ("~/Maintenance/_TitleDetails") }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

It then hard codes the tilda into the url .0.43/~/Maintenace....  instead of substituting it.

Comment: Did you try `Url.Action()`?

Comment: Hi Shoe, I did not, can you elaborate?  thanks!

Comment: `Url.Content` needs to point to a valid absolute path. I am guessing yours points to an action/controller.

Comment: yes i think? have updated with a line of code that got it working but hoping there is a better way

Comment: What is `Maintenance`? What is `_TitleDetails`? A controller and an action?

Comment: Yes maintenance is the controller and _TitleDetails the action/view

Comment: I'm wondering the if i set the ip/app name to be a single name, would any of this be needed?

Comment: If you're point to an action/controller then you need to use `Url.Action("Maintenance", "_TitleDetails")` instead of `Url.Content`

Comment: Worked a treat thanks, although i had to change it to be Url.Action("_TitleDetails", "Maintenance")

What is the best way for using this in Html5?  I generate a html tree menu from a sql table

<a class="PartialLink" href="@i.NavURL">@i.MenuName</a> but need to prefix that with the url base context also

Comment: Use the overload `Url.Action("action", "controller", routevalues, Request.Url.Scheme)` and you'll get an absolute url rather than a relative one.